# eqiuvalent norms in $H_0^2$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I have found that the $H^2(D)$ norm of a field with zero Cauchy data on $\partial D$ (i.e. in $H_0^2(D)$) is equivalent to the $L^2(D)$ norm of its Laplacian, where D is simply connected with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How can i prove this using Poincare inequality;

Comment: There's also a similar result for functions without zero boundary data, but it's harder to prove: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/273563)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that we have the following Poincaré inequality for $H^2_0(D)$:
$$\|u\|_{H^2_0(D)} \leq C \|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)}^2.$$
This is obtained by chaining the Poincaré inequality for $u$ with the Poincaré inequality for $Du$. Therefore we may take
$$\|u\|_\ast^2 = \|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)}^2$$
as our norm on $H^2_0(D)$, as it is equivalent to the standard $H^2_0(D)$ norm.

We claim that
$$\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(D)} = \|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)} = \|u\|_\ast$$
for any $u \in H_0^2(D)$. To see this, first consider $u \in C_0^\infty(D)$. Then integration by parts and commutativity of partial derivatives for smooth functions implies
$$\int_D u_{x_i x_i} u_{x_j x_j} ~dx = -\int_D u_{x_i} u_{x_j x_j x_i} ~dx = - \int_D u_{x_i} u_{x_j x_i x_j} ~dx = \int_D u_{x_i x_j} u_{x_i x_j} ~dx$$
for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$. Summing over all $i$ and $j$ then gives
$$\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(D)} = \|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)}$$
for all $u \in C_0^\infty(D)$. Since $C_0^\infty(D)$ is dense in $H_0^2(D)$, passing to limits we find that
$$\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(D)} = \|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)} \text{ for all } u \in H_0^2(D).$$
This gives the desired equality of norms.

Comment: thanks a lot, the only thing i can't see is the poincare inequality for $H_0^2$. I thought that it was $∥u∥_{H^2_0}(D)^2≤C\sum_{|a|=2}∥D^au∥^2L_2(D)$..i must be missing something!

Comment: In my notation, $\|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)}$ means $$\|D^2 u\|_{L^2(D)} = \left( \sum_{|\alpha| = 2} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^2(D)}^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$ This is the notation used throughout Evans's _Partial Differential Equations_.

Comment: great!thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this holds if we consider $H^2$ instead of $H^2_0$?

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering whether this generalizes to other $p \neq 2$. Do you know anything about that?