# Showing $\lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2} + \lVert u \rVert_{L^2}$ is equivalent to $\|u\|_{H^2}$ norm for $H^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/273563/360262) showing  $\lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2(U)} + \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(U)}$ is equivalent to $\|u\|_{H^2(U)}$ norm for $H^2(U)$ space assuming the domain $U$ is sufficient smooth. However I came across some problem when following the hint below the post,
I do as follows:

Consider $u \in H^2(U)$ it satisfies the equation :

$$\Delta u = f \\ u = g\ \text{  on }\ \partial U $$

By the elliptic reguarity we have $$\|u\|_{H^2} \le C(\|u\|_{L^2 } + \|f\|_{L^2} + \|g\|_{H^2(U)})$$

The problem here differs from the problem for equivalent norm in $H = H^1_0 \cap H^2$ is that this equation above does not has homogenuous boundary condition, therefore the regularity result has $\|g\|_{H^2(U)}$ in it correct.I have no idea how to bound this term.

Comment: apply the estimate for the problem with homogeneous boundary conditions to $u-g$.

Comment: also the statement is FALSE without assumptions on $\Omega$, see any textbook on PDEs, e.g., Evans

Comment: Can you elaborate more , $\|u\|_{H^2} - \|g\|_{H^2(U)}\le \|u-g\|_{H^2(U)} \le \|f- \Delta g\|_{L^2(U)}$ still involves norm of $g$, I don't have enough knowledge to deal with norm of $g$ @daw